# Cookies for domain and subdomain with passport.js

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, passport.js

Basically, I have a sign-in form, running on AUTH.domain.com and I create a session (saved in cookie) for the logged users. Then I redirect the user to APP.domain.com, and I need his session to be passed also to this subdomain, but we can't figure, how to do that.
Authorization works with passport.js, and session set from passport.js

I tried set domain option on cookies middleware and set `res.sessionOption.domain = '.domain.com'`. But this does work.

```
app.use(cookiesession({
    secret: 'secretstring',
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: true,
    domain: '.domain.com'
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

req.sessionOptions.domain = '.domain.com';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the domain to `domain.com` (note the omission of the preceding `.`)!